# How to remove the blank spaces between two lines in a column

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a column that returns the following output:

```
PERSON_NUMBER                                    FEEDBACK
13636                                         -Very attentive during our sessions
                                            
                                              -Very interative session, questions 
                                                were asked and answered well.
                                            


                                              Nice turn over 

                                              Debates were good
```

I want the output of FEEDBACK Column to look like:

```
PERSON_NUMBER                                    FEEDBACK
13636                                         -Very attentive during our sessions                                           
                                              -Very interative session, questions 
                                                were asked and answered well.
                                              Nice turn over 
                                              Debates were good
```

I.e. the extra blank spaces between the lines should be removed.

Comment: Those look like blank lines - any reason you call them "spaces"? A blank space is a single space between two words on the same line.

Answer (score 2):

You could do a regex replacement on `(?:\r?\n){2,}` and replace with just a single CR?LF:

```sql
SELECT PERSON_NUMBER,
       REGEXP_REPLACE(FEEDBACK,
                      '(' || chr(13) || '?' || chr(10) || '){2,}',
                      chr(13) || chr(10)) AS FEEDBACK
FROM yourTable;
```

Comment: I used the exact same query, but I am getting <p>,<p>&nbsp;</p> in the output..... anyway I can remove that ?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to remove all the lines that **look** empty (e.g. that may also contain spaces, tabs or other non-printable characters), then you may use negation of the `[:graph:]` class in the regex to find such rows and replace them with empty row and then replace all newline repetitions with single one.

Below is the code:

> ```
> with a as (
>   select q'[-Very attentive during our sessions
>                                             
> -Very interative session, questions 
>  were asked and answered well.]' || chr(13) || chr(10) || q'[
>                                             
>        ]' || chr(10) || q'[      
>
> ]' || chr(10) || chr(10) || q'[Nice turn over]' as q
> from dual
> )
> select
>   regexp_replace(
>     regexp_replace(
>       q,
>       /*
>         Replace LF followed by any non-printable sequence that ends with newline
>         with single newline
>       */
>       chr(10) || '[^[:graph:]]*(' || chr(13) || '?' || chr(10) || ')',
>       chr(10) || '\1'
>     ),
>     /*Then replace newline repetitions*/
>     '(' || chr(13) || '?' || chr(10) || ')+',
>     '\1'
>   ) as q
> from a
> ```

| q |
| --- |
| -Very attentive during our sessions -Very interative session, questions were asked and answered well. Nice turn over |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=c5353f083d1b2fb835ec00cf6655a6bd)*

Comment: I used the exact same query, but I am getting <p>,<p>&nbsp;</p> in the output..... anyway I can remove that ?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I do not know what you are talking about. What is the input to the query? You may check the output of the above code by running it in the linked fiddle.